# How to keep the children of a React Native Modal mounted when the modal is closed?

Tags: react-native

I have a certain component that stutters a bit when it's mounted, and I need to place it inside a modal that will be opened and closed by the user.

So that it doesn't stutter every time the user opens the modal, I would like to have this component to always stay mounted, even when the modal is closed/invisible.

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/MJM27ORCQ)